# gradle build file shows error during build

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, build.gradle

When I merged to different build.gradle file to integrate two different functionality to one it shows error as follows-

```
startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\sobhit.s\Pictures\API-Update\build.gradle': 89: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script

See https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block

 @ line 89, column 1.
   buildscript {
   ^

1 error

Open File

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'java'    
group 'api_automation'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'   
sourceCompatibility = 1.8    
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
} 
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("test-output/reports/")
    }
    useTestNG()
            {
                useDefaultListeners = true
                options.suites("src/test/java/testApi_Test_Scripts/smsApiAutomationSuite.xml")
                            }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
    test {
        runtimeClasspath = files(output.resourcesDir) + runtimeClasspath
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.0.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'rest-assured', version: '3.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
    //An assertion library that is better than JUnit defaults
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    //Better reporting for testng.  It outputs a nice html report
    testCompile 'org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor', name: 'htmlcompressor', version: '1.5.2'
    compile group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: "com.github.fge", name: "json-schema-validator", version: "2.2.6"
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.guice-repository', name: 'guice-repository', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.easytesting', name: 'fest-assert-core', version: '2.0M10'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile 'com.relevantcodes:extentreports:2.41.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'
    compile 'software.amazon.awssdk:kinesis'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.534'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.539'
    compileClasspath group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.+'
}
test {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

This is the build.gradle after merging. Also I am not sure whats standard way of creating build.gradle. Any help would really be appreciated.

I just added build.script and mavem bom from then its an issue.

[image: AWS which I added to my existing and got the above one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your merged script you are mixing both notations for applying Gradle plugins:  the `buildscript{}` notation and the `plugins {}` DSL ( see more information about these two notations here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:binary_plugins )

While this is possible to mix both notations, there is a Gradle constraint: you must place `plugins{}` block at first position in the script, but if you also have a `buildscript{}` block then it has to be placed before `plugins{}` block. 
(I'll try to find pointer to this constraint in the official documentation)

EDIT : see description of the `plugins{}` block contraints [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:constrained_syntax):

> The plugins {} block must also be a top level statement in the buildscript. It cannot be nested inside another construct (e.g. an if-statement or for-loop)

So: just move the `buildscript {}` block at top of your script.

Note : a better solution would be to get rid of the `buildscript {}` block, which is the 'old' syntax:

use:

```
plugins {
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
}
```

instead of

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
     classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.7.RELEASE"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are genius.

Comment: @M.Riccuti But now its giving me classpath error in my entire project.

Comment: @SobhitSharma now this is another issue, you need to check your dependencies to find the missing/conflicting one. the initial question was about build script error, which was solved. you have no reason to un-accept the previously accepted answer. please check your dependencies carefully, or open another question to ask for help